# onFocus and onBlur

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onblur, onfocus

For some reason the `onblur` and `onfocus` properties don't work. Am I defining them right?

```
var replyTxt = document.createElement("input");
    replyTxt.id="replyTxt";
    replyTxt.type="text";
    replyTxt.value="Write a reply";
    
    replyTxt.onfocus = function(){if(replyTxt.value==replyTxt.defaultValue) replyTxt.value='';};
    replyTxt.onblur= function(){if(replyTxt.value=='') replyTxt.value=replyTxt.defaultValue;};
```

I have also tried putting `"function(){if(replyTxt.value==replyTxt.defaultValue) replyTxt.value='';}"` in quotations

Comment: Actually it should work.I dunno  why it doesnt ??

Comment: No setting of defaultValue. Also some sort of closure was done inside the anonymous functions where `this.value` would be a better choice than `replyTxt.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events work - so there may be a problem with your logic...

```
if(replyTxt.value==replyTxt.defaultValue) replyTxt.value='';
```

Where do you set replyTxt.defaultValue? In your example, you don't - so the logic will never fire. Try this...

```
var replyTxtDefaultText = "Write a reply";
var replyTxt = document.createElement("input");
    replyTxt.id="replyTxt";
    replyTxt.type="text";
    replyTxt.value=replyTxtDefaultText;

    replyTxt.onfocus = function(){if(replyTxt.value==replyTxtDefaultText) replyTxt.value='';};
    replyTxt.onblur= function(){if(replyTxt.value=='') replyTxt.value=replyTxtDefaultText;};
```

Comment: Using this. instead of replyTxt in the function is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint:
try replacing `replyTxt` with `this` in your event functions.

Comment: That is important! But it does seem to work regardless. Closure perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

try `setAttribute`. more information about function take a look this [link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute)

```
var replyTxt = document.createElement("input");
replyTxt.setAttribute('onFocus', 'focusFunction()');

function focusFunction()
{
   if(replyTxt.value==replyTxtDefaultText) 
      replyTxt.value='';
}
```

Comment: Why do you wrap the function call inside a string? Don't do that. Ever. Again.

Answer (score 0):

And make sure you append it to something.

```
<form id="x">
</form>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  var replyTxt = document.createElement("input");
  replyTxt.id="replyTxt";
  replyTxt.type="text";
  replyTxt.value=replyTxt.defaultValue="Write a reply";
  replyTxt.onfocus = function(){if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';};
  replyTxt.onblur= function(){if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;};

  document.getElementById('x').appendChild(replyTxt);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually I was working on a similar problem as a homework and I found out that is better to clear the field as soon as the mouse lands on the field rather than making a comparison if left untouched and then clear it.