# Does dojo TabContainer have an event thats triggered when changing tabs?

Tags: javascript, dojo

does DOJO TabContainer have an event thats triggered when changing tabs?

I imagine it would but I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. :(

SOLVED: It looks like I found a solution here:

[Dijit TabContainer Events - onFocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262740/dijit-tabcontainer-events-onfocus)

not the most searchable topic title :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connect `aspect.after` to TabContainer's `selectChild` method:

```
var tabContainer1 = registry.byId("tabContainer1");

aspect.after(tabContainer1, "selectChild", function() {
    console.log("tab changed");        
});
```

Or if you are interested in a particular tab, connect to its ContentPane's `_onShow`:

```
var contentPane1 = registry.byId("contentPane1");

aspect.after(contentPane1, "_onShow", function() {
    console.log("[first] tab selected");        
});
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/Mdh4w/

Comment: Ah, I'm actually using dojo 1.61, but aspect wasn't introduced until 1.7. I've found a solution using the _transition event though. I'll post it after 8 hours time period.

Comment: Aspect is in Dojo since its beginnings, just use `dojo.connect` instead of `aspect.after`. It's the same.

Comment: Ah, dojo.connect works. dojo.require("dojo.aspect") wasn't supported until 1.7.

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html);

```
var tabs = registry.byId('someTabs');
tabs.watch("selectedChildWidget", function(name, oval, nval){
    console.log("selected child changed from ", oval, " to ", nval);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @phusick's answer, which is correct, all `StackContainer`s, including the `TabContainer` publish on topics that you can subscribe to.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/layout/StackContainer.html#published-topics

```
[widgetId]-addChild,
[widgetId]-removeChild
[widgetId]-selectChild
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/subscribe.html#dojo-subscribe

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking at `StackContainer::selectChild` method source code quite surprised seeing `topic.publish(this.id+"-selectChild", page)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete code sample that works in Dojo 1.8, I've tested it. It's not an event that fires just on changing tabs, I couldn't get any of their events in the API to fire, but at least it works on the Click event.

```
require(["dijit/registry",  "dojo/on", "dojo/ready", "dojo/domReady!"], function (registry, on, ready) {
    ready(function () { //wait till dom is parsed into dijits
        var panel = registry.byId('mainTab');   //get dijit from its source dom element
        on(panel, "Click", function (event) {   //for some reason onClick event doesn't work 
            $('.hidden_field_id').val(panel.selectedChildWidget.id);  //on click, save the selected child to a hidden field somewhere. this $ is jquery, just change it to 'dojo.query()'
        });
    });
});

//include this function if you want to reselect the tab on page load after a postback
require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dojo/domReady!"], function (registry, ready) {
    ready(function () {
        var tabId = $('.hidden_field_id').val();
        if (tabId == null || tabId == "")
            return;
        var panel = registry.byId('mainTab');
        var tab = registry.byId(tabId);
        panel.selectChild(tab);
    });
});
```